# Azure HTTP trigger function call returning 417 error code

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am using a azure http triggered fucntion to perform a task and I am passing the function key as http header parameter and then my payload is a json with some data that I invoking down stream procedures.I am using urllib(python lib) for this request and this is the response I am getting but the function is getting triggered.

urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 417: Expectation Failed

Comment: Can you look at the log on the azure portal ? Can you share your code please

Comment: Which the version of your urllib? Please post more details about your code in function.

Answer (score 0):

This was more of a Firewall issue.We have been trying to connect to a azure analysis service from ADW and we have added the IP filtering(Our Corporate public IP) for AAS and then when the Function's procedure is trying to connected to AAS it is facing some IP issue(this is NOT the corporate public IP). We have added that IP and now things are working fine.